# Hi, I have a problem handling errors in Flutter with the Bloc library. the try catch block does not catch the error

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, error-handling, bloc

I tried debugging on the function excursionss and  the error is correctly propagated up to handleError method, but this error is not rethrown until the try catch of the Bloc:

```
Stream<List<Excursion>> excursionss() {
  return firebaseFirestore
      .collection('Excursions')
      .snapshots()
      .asyncMap((snapshot) async {
    List<Excursion> excursions = [];
    for (var excursionSnapshot in snapshot.docs) {
      try {
        Excursion excursion =
            await excursionMapper.fromFirebaseAsync(excursionSnapshot.data());
        excursions.add(excursion);
      } catch (e) {
        throw ExcursionRepositoryException(e);
      }
    }
    return excursions;
  }).handleError((error) {
    throw ExcursionRepositoryException(error);
  }, test: (e) => e is Exception);
}
```

The Bloc code:
the log on DataStream prints _HandleErrorStream, but the try catch block doesn't get the error.

```
class InitialDataBloc extends Bloc<DownloadDataEvent, DownloadDataState> {
  final ExcursionMapper excursionMapper;
  final FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
  final ExcursionRepository excursionRepository;

  InitialDataBloc({
    required this.firebaseFirestore,

    required this.excursionRepository,
    required this.excursionMapper,
  }) : super(OnDownloadDataState()) {
    on<DownloadDataEvent>(_downloadExcursions);
  }

  FutureOr<void> _downloadExcursions(
      DownloadDataEvent event, Emitter<DownloadDataState> emit) async {
    emit(OnDownloadDataState());
    try {
      final dataStream = await excursionRepository.excursionss();
      log(dataStream.toString());
      emit(DataFetchedState(excursions: dataStream));
    } catch (error) {
      emit(ErrorDownloadDataState(error));
    }
  }

  void downloadExcursion() => add(OnDownloadDataEvent());
}
```

Comment: Any code about `ExcursionRepositoryException`?

Comment: class ExcursionRepositoryException implements Exception {
  ExcursionRepositoryException();
} it is an empty class